# How to solve Rudin Chapter 2 problem 11?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have finished the entire problem except the 5th part. Roughly speaking the questions asks to show that over $\mathbb{R}$ prove/disprove that the distance function

$$ d_5(x,y) = \frac{|x-y|}{1 + |x-y|} $$

Is a metric. I have proven symmetry and I have proven that if $d_5(x,y) = 0$ that $x = y$ so all that remains to be shown is the triangle inequality namely :

$$ \frac{|x-y|}{1 + |x-y|}+ \frac{|y-z|}{1 + |y-z|} \ge \frac{|x-z|}{1 + |x-z|} $$

This of course can be cast more simply in terms of $u,v$ in $\mathbb{R}$ as

$$ \frac{|u|}{1 + |u|}+ \frac{|v|}{1 + |v|} \ge \frac{|u+v|}{1 + |u+v|} $$

This reminds me an awful lot of contest style inequalities but i can't for the love of god place which one this is (not that it should matter, I should ideally be able to just generate a proof with ease).

My one angle of attack was to do case work on fixing $u,v$ to be both positive or both negative, or a mix of positive and negative. But is there a easier way to proceed than that?

Comment: You might also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672881/given-positive-real-numbers-a-b-c-with-abc-show-that-a-1ab-1bc/672980#comment1413813_672881).

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1104633/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/297818/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1803416/42969 – all found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24d(x%2Cy)%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B%7Cx-y%7C%7D%7B1%20%2B%20%7Cx-y%7C%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{|u+v|}{1+|u+v|}&=1-\dfrac{1}{1+|u+v|}\\
&\leq1-\dfrac{1}{1+|u|+|v|}\\
&=\dfrac{|u|+|v|}{1+|u|+|v|}\\
&=\dfrac{|u|}{1+|u|+|v|}+\dfrac{|v|}{1+|u|+|v|}\\
&\leq\dfrac{|u|}{1+|u|}+\dfrac{|v|}{1+|v|}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Very nice, so easy to follow, not so easy to come up with .