# Let $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, when does $|x-y|^p$ define a metric?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> For what $p$ does $|x-y|^p$ define a metric on $\mathbb{R}$?

One can show that $d_1 = \sqrt{|x-y|}=|x-y|^\frac{1}{2}$ defineds a metric. All requirements can be easily checked. On the other hand, $d_2 = |x-y|^2$ does not define a metric. For example,

$$|1-0|^2=1\text{ , but } |1-0.5|^2+|0.5-0|^2=0.5$$

I am curious for what $p$ does $|x-y|^p$ define a metric? I suspect that if $p>1$ then it cannot be a metric since we can use the similar arguments using $0,0.5$ and $1$.

Comment: If $p>1$ then it dont defines a metric. Observe that the same example you used can be applied for any $p>1$. For $0< p\le 1$ it defines a metric. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#When_0_.3C_p_.3C_1). What I dont checked are the cases for negative values of $p$.

Comment: See also [this posts](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134714/does-xp-with-0p1-satisfy-the-triangle-inequality-on-mathbbr) and other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/134714).
Perhaps also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987602/composition-of-a-function-with-a-metric).

Answer (score 5):

The only thing we need to check is the triangle inequality, i.e. for what $p$, do we have
\begin{align}
|x-y|^p \leq |x-z|^p+|z-y|^p.
\end{align}
It's clear that for $p>1$ the above inequality fails because
\begin{align}
2^p=|1-(-1)|^p< |1-0|^p+|0-(-1)|^p  = 2.
\end{align}
Suppose $0<p\leq 1$, then we see the triangle iequality does hold. Let us prove it. Observe
\begin{align}
|x+y| \leq (|x|+|y|)= (|x|^{p/p}+|y|^{p/p}) \leq  (|x|^p+|y|^p)^{1/p}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
|x+y|^p \leq |x|^p+|y|^p.
\end{align}
Lastly, for $p<0$, we see that $1/|x-y|^{|p|}$ doesn't satisfies the condition $d(x, x) = 0$.

Comment: How do we get $(|x|^{p/p} + |y|^{p/p})\le (|x|^p + |y|^p)^{1/p}$?

Comment: @3x89g2 The relation $(|x|^{p/p} + |y|^{p/p}) < (|x|^p + |y|^p)^{1/p}$ just states that the 1-norm is less than the p-norm, for $p\le 1$. This is true since in general, $p$-norms are decreasing with $p$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218046/