# $||x|^\alpha-|y|^\alpha|\le|x-y|^\alpha$, $\alpha\ge0.5$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How can I show that $||x|^\alpha-|y|^\alpha|\le|x-y|^\alpha$ for $\alpha\ge0.5$?

I couldn’t even show it for $\alpha=0.5$ How could I go about proving it ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: It's not hard to prove $(a+b)^α\leqslant a^α+b^α$ by examining $f(t)=(t+b)^α-t^α$.

Comment: Actually I am not sure how to proceed . I tried to play around a bit but didn’t go far . Even a hint would

Comment: Be highly appreciated .

Comment: False for $\alpha >1$. For $\alpha <1$ don't get carried away by the condition $\alpha \geq 0.5$ The inequality is true for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

Comment: Then I am at a loss . I am trying to understand  strong uniqueness of the one dimensional SDE $dX_t=\vert X_s\vert^\alpha dW_s$ for $\alpha\ge 0.5 $ as in the paper of Girsanov 1962 via the Yamada Watanabe condition in their paper of 1971 on the dispersion coefficient . Karatzas and Shreve in the  Brownian motion book on page 292 in example 2.15  imply that the inequality I asked to prove actually holds . I am going to read more carefully , perhaps I misunderstood their example .  Thank you for your comment

Comment: Let $\alpha = 2, y=2, x=1$. Then you have 
$
\vert 1^2- 2^2 \vert \le \vert 1-2 \vert^2 \quad \rightarrow \quad 3 \le 1 
$ which is wrong. Is suggest changing the question with "for $0<\alpha<1$".

Comment: Are you sure that in the sources you cited, that you need ALL $\alpha>0.5$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Note: This inequality holds for all $0< p \leq 1$

Define $$d: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$$ by $$d(x,y)=|x-y|^p$$

Now you can show that this function $d$ defines a metric for $0<p \leq 1$. Read the proof here [Let $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, when does $|x-y|^p$ define a metric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970474/let-dx-y-x-y-when-does-x-yp-define-a-metric)

Now observe that inequality in the question is nothing but the reverse triangle inequality which says that $$ \forall x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}: \left|{d \left({x, z}\right) - d \left({y, z}\right)}\right| \le d \left({x, y}\right)$$

Put $z=0$ and you are done!!

P.S. for proof of reverse triangle inequality 
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Reverse_Triangle_Inequality